# Symfony2 DoctrineFixturesBundle namespace error

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, fixtures

I have a big problem with the fixtures bundle which I can't resolve. I 
follow the steps as they are meant to be followed, adding the lines to 
the deps file, installing them, registering them in the autoload and 
appkernel.

When I try to run even only `app/console`, it breaks with:

`Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\DoctrineCommand' 
not found in /var/www/.../bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle/ 
Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php on line 40`

Which seems right because I don't have a DoctrineBundle directory 
under `Doctrine\Bundle`, only the `DoctrineFixturesBundle`. 
If I change that line to `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\...` it works 
perfectly, because that class resides under that namespace actually.

Of course I can't leave it that way. 
I searched through the documentation, issues, everything, but it seems 
that noone has this same issue, so I must be missing some obvious 
point here.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not long ago, all [Doctrine bundles moved to the Doctrine organizaton](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-1-the-doctrine-bundle-has-moved-to-the-doctrine-organization). This causes some confusion based on which repository and branch you are using.

If you're using Symfony 2.0.x, then your `deps` should look something like this:

```
[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

Notice the target/namespace is actually `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle`.

---

However, you shouldn't have any problems using the latest `DoctrineFixturesBundle` with Symfony 2.0.x - as long as you upgrade the rest of the Doctrine dependencies also. You can use this in your `deps` instead:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.0

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.0

[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated my deps file the way you pasted here. My vendor structure remains the same tho, so my DoctrineBundle is still not in the Doctrine\Bundle\ namespace, so I get the same error message.

Comment: I'm using this symfony version:[symfony]
    git=git://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.11

Comment: When changing your deps file (especially when altering versions), you will need to remove the `deps.lock` file before running `php bin/vendors update` or `php bin/vendors install`. When all else fails, delete both `deps.lock` and the contents of your `vendor` directory before running the vendors install script.

Comment: Also, the DoctrineBundle will never be in the `Doctrine\Bundle` namespace as long as you are on Symfony 2.0.x. Symfony 2.0.x ships with the DoctrineBundle under `bundles\Symfony`. Your problem is that you are trying to use a too new version of the DoctrineFixturesBundle which expects the DoctrineBundle under `Doctrine\Bundle`. My first suggestion, tagging the bundle to `version=origin/2.0` should solve this.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments. Finally I managed to get it working. I used the old deps code for the FixturesBundle, and targeted it to Symfony\Bundle and not to Doctrine\Bundle. I was losing my mind on this. I don't know what will happen when 2.1 comes out tho, lol.
Thank you a lot again.